# divs rightmost column pushed down on small screens

Tags: html, css

This is the structure of my html template, and it works fine when displaying my webpage on a large screen (pc's monitor) but not so on smaller ones (phone's screen), the rightmost column is displayed at the bottom of the page rather than at the right, what I need is that instead of shifting the column to the bottom of the page, can I just make the page have horizontal scrolling? and that the rightmost div never gets pushed to the bottom?

```
<div>
   <div style="float:left;">
   </div>
   <div style="float:left;">
   <pre>  </pre>
   <!--Just to create space-->
   </div>
   <div style="float:left;">
   </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:left"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's what happens when you're using floats and not seting width of the parent element.
You can set min-width ( or just width should do fine ) of the parent element or use div sizes in %, and / or use display: table;, not float. 
Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/c995v/`

```
<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <div style="float:left;">first float left</div>
        <div style="float:left;"> <pre> second float left </pre>

            <!--Just to create space-->
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;">third float left</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:left"></div>
</body>
```